# How to add product progmatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7

How can i add product using php scripts in magento base directory in magento 2, as **Mage class has been eliminated** ??

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a stand alone script in the following manner

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

class TestApp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{
    public function launch()
    {
       /** IMPORT CODE HERE **/
        $importObject = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product');


        return $this->_response;
    }

    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

- you can call any class from magento with the object manager (not recommended) or via constructor(DI) - I do not know if in this case works with DI ,haven't tried, that's why I showed you the object manager way.
- for importing products you can start by debugging the class Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product and especially the _saveProducts method.

Hope it helps!